# SwiftUI: Data in list appears sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a problem. In my application, I have CoreData with devices and the IP of the devices. I want to make an API request to fetch JSON data from a selected device and show them in a list. My problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes it does not and the list does not update when I change the data. I hope someone can help me.

BouquetAPIModel.swift

```swift
struct BouquetAPIModel: Codable {
    let success: String
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let bouquets: [Bouquet]
}

// MARK: - Bouquet
struct Bouquet: Codable {
    var number, name: String
}
```

Device.swift

```swift
public class Device: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var bouquets : [Bouquet] = [Bouquet]()

    func fetchBouquetList() {
        fetchAPIRequest(apiPath: "/control/getbouquets?format=json") { (res: Result<BouquetAPIModel, Error>) in
            switch res {
            case .success(let bouquets):
                self.bouquets = bouquets.data.bouquets
            case .failure(let err):
                print("Fail to fetch bouquets: ", err)
            }
        }
    }


    fileprivate func fetchAPIRequest<T: Decodable>(apiPath: String, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> ()) {
        let urlString = getApiUrl(apiPath: apiPath)
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,resp, err) in

            if let err = err {
                completion(.failure(err))
                return
            }

            do {
                let welcome = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!)
                completion(.success(welcome))
            } catch let jsonError {
                completion(.failure(jsonError))
            }

        }.resume()    
    }
```

BouquetView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BouquetView: View {
    @Binding  var device : Device?
    @State var bouquets: [Bouquet] = [Bouquet]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(device?.deviceName ?? "fehler")).onTapGesture {
                self.device?.bouquets.removeFirst()
                print("Touch")
            }
            List (self.bouquets, id: \Bouquet.name) { bouquet in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(bouquet.name)
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadBouquets)
    }

    func loadBouquets() {
        if device == nil {
            //TODO jumo to settings
        }
        else {
            device?.fetchBouquetList()
            self.bouquets = device!.bouquets
        }
    }
}

struct BouquetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BouquetView(device: .constant(nil))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you update your Device like below?

```
public class Device: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
...
}
```

And make sure you declare your device with annotation `@ObservedObject` before passing to `BouquetView`

Comment: brings Error: Redundant conformance of 'Device' to protocol 'ObservableObject'

Comment: Please try with the new update, `ObserverableObject` is conforming Types `NSManagedObject` so get rid of `NSManagedObject`

Comment: then i get Type 'Device' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult' in another view where i use Fetchrequest for core data

Comment: It is a different scenario to handle with the core data. You can try with this case to make sure the data is loaded from the server and update in your view.

Comment: But i need the IP from the Coradata Object to try

Comment: You can create a new class to handle the fetching data from the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205256/discussion-between-liem-vo-and-ezak).

Answer (score 0):

Fetching might be long, so you've got into racing. To avoid it the followings approach might be used

1) remove the following line as data might not be ready yet at this point

```
self.bouquets = device!.bouquets
```

2) add explicit listener for data set

```
if device == nil {
    //TODO jumo to settings
    device!.$bouquets
       .assign(to: \.bouquets, on: self)
       .store(in: &cancellables) // << you will need to create this store var
}
```

Comment: in if or in else ?

Comment: in `if`, because `loadBouquets` can be called many times as I assume, but subscriber have to be assigned only once.

Comment: but device is never nil

Comment: It is your code... and it is optional. If it is never nil, then why it is optional? And if it is not then you can put subscriber assignment in `init` similar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569036/12299030)

Comment: It could be nil if no dive is selected in another view, but i select one. I try with init

Comment: with a new class like in @Liem Vo s answer helps me.