# How to "forward" a @Published value

Tags: swiftui, combine

I am very new to SwiftUI and Combine, and even though I have plenty of experience with Swift, and a bit with ReactiveKit, I am finding it hard to get some basic stuff to work.

For example, I am trying to add an `isLoggedIn` property on my ViewModel, which should simply "forward" the `UserManager` class' `isLoggedIn` property. With ReactiveKit this is rather trivial but with SwiftUI/Combine I can't get is to work. The value is only set once, and then never updated again.

```swift
class UserManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published private(set) var isLoggedIn = false

  // This class has all the actual logic for logging in, 
  // keeping track of the logged in user and the auth status, etc.
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isLoggedIn = false

  private let userManager: UserManager

  init(userManager: UserManager) {
    self.userManager = userManager
    isLoggedIn = userManager.isLoggedIn // <- this doesn't work
    userManager.$isLoggedIn.assign(to: \.isLoggedIn, on: self) // <- neither does this
  }

  func logout() {
    userManager.logout()
  }
}

struct ContentView: View  {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

  var body: some View {
    // this will use viewModel.isLoggedIn at some point
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work. If you don't store subscriber it cancelled automatically.

```
  private var subscribers = [AnyCancellable]()
  init(userManager: UserManager) {
    self.userManager = userManager
    userManager.$isLoggedIn
       .assign(to: \.isLoggedIn, on: self)
       .store(in: &subscribers) // << subscriber must be kept
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to replace the @Published var isLoggedIn in your ViewModel with a manual objectWillChange.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  var isLoggedIn: Bool {userManager.isLoggedIn}

  private let userManager: UserManager
  private var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable?

  init(userManager: UserManager) {
    self.userManager = userManager

    anyCancellable = userManager.objectWillChange.sink {[weak self] _ in
      self?.objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }

}
```